# value_counts() vs groupby('xxx').sum()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I can't figure out why those two methods give different results.

Dataframe:
[chipo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv)

```
chipo['choice_description'].value_counts().head(1)

chipo.groupby('choice_description').sum().sort_values(by='quantity', ascending=False).head(1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: chipo.groupby('choice_description')['choice_description'].count() will give your same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value_counts()` is, count values without looking at what the value actually is. So 1 and 100 on that column will be treated as the same -- you have one count.

`sum()`, however, sum up the columns. So if you have two rows, one is 1 and another is 100, your sum is 101 while the count is 2.